# How to execute a file in separate gnome terminal in linux

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I want to execute a C program in separate terminal, I've tried this command,

```
gnome-terminal -x ./test
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -e test
```

But it opens a new terminal and before giving me output, it just vanish.

How could I solve this issue using `gnome-terminal`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do note that `... test` and `... ./test` are not the same thing, unless you've had the misfortunate advice to put `.` before everything else in your `PATH`, and even then, depending on what shell you're using, the first may still invoke the builtin `test` command instead of your script. `test` is a horrible (although logical and intuitive) name for a test script... ;-P

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you search:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"!!; exec bash\""
```

or (shortly):

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "!!; bash"
```

It opens gnome-terminal with your last command (!!) executed and it stays open with the command output in the shell, even with an interactive command like top or less...

In your case its:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"./test; exec bash\""
```

or

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./test; bash"
```